# how can I parse json-ld to markdown

Tags: parsing, markdown, json-ld

Is there an existing parser to parse json-ld to markdown? I want to generate documentation from my jsonld file. If such a thing doesn't exist, how should I go ahead writing one? or perhaps I could use a json to markdown converter? Any suggestions on how could do this?

Answer (score 2):

I was just googling for such a program, and found your question.

The closest things I could find are: [ocxmd](https://github.com/philbarker/ocxmd), which is an extension to Markdown; and [md-ld](https://github.com/hubgit/md-ld), which does not even use proper Markdown - instead, it apparently creates an incompatible version of the format which can be parsed to JSON-LD.

If I were writing such a converter in Python, I would use:

- [pyld](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/pyld) to parse JSON-LD files and expand them using the `@context`;
- And a template engine, likely Jinja2, to generate Markdown representation of every node of the JSON-LD document.

The program would be based on recursion. You might have separate functions to display:

- URIs,
- Numbers,
- Images,
- ...

The program will recurse over the JSON-LD document and convert each of its sections into Markdown format.